# Mongodb compound indexes for filtering and sorting on BIG collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index

Can somebody tell me please if is possible to make indexes in Mongodb more efficient in this case: I have database with 50 millions items. There are two indexes on fields "ico" and "publishDate". Ico is used for **filtering** and publishDate for **sorting**. Is it possible to make it like a **compound index** to be more efficient? Can I combine filtering and sorting in compound index? Is important to choose which one should be the first in index definition? It is little complicated cause I have not the collection on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a compound index as `{ico: 1, publishDate: 1}`.  Refer to [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/).

Comment: Why you choose ico as first field in index? As documentation said it is important in case if I want to use ico filter without order by publishDate. But is it important if I use both fields all the time? I made the index few minutes ago and I used publishDate first.

Comment: See https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/ for a detailed explanation