# MongoDB - explain.executionStats

Tags: mongodb, explain

Are there any elements within the output of MongoDB's explain("executionStats") that gives an idea or a hint about - whether the query is using a given index for filtering or sorting or for both?

I read the following URLs

[Mongodb compound indexes for filtering and sorting on BIG collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748271/mongodb-compound-indexes-for-filtering-and-sorting-on-big-collection) [points to below URL and has brief discussion]

https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/ [ this one gives general idea, but the explain output uses older format/elements that don't exist in Mongodb 4.0 that I am using ]

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/ [documents how to determine the index and leverage index prefixes, but does show explain output confirming the usage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MongoDB [Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#sort-stage):

> If MongoDB can use an index scan to obtain the requested sort order,
>   the result will not include a SORT stage. Otherwise, if MongoDB cannot
>   use the index to sort, the explain result will include a SORT stage.

**Example:**

Look at the sample data from sortop collection.
[image]

Explain plan for a query without index:
[image]

Create Index on the collection:

[image]

Run the same query and check SORT stage in explain plan:
[image]